# Rebinding the physical Touchpad Keys on a ThinkPad

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, touchpad, thinkpad, synaptic

I have been sitting on this problem for a couple of hours now but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have gotten myself a new ThinkPad and it has 3 discrete buttons above the trackpad. I've installed the xf86-input-synaptics and the trackpad works as it should how ever said 3 buttons are having some odd funtions I want to remap. At the moment the left and right button scroll up and down accordingly and it want them to remap to left and right mouse click. I know you are supposed to use synclient to configure your trackpad but I can't even seem to grasp the usage and how to define the rule.

I hope someone of you can help me to get this thing reconfigured.

Thanks!